# Isekai manga where the female main character summons a metal/iron spirit that's not supposed to exist

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai, reincarnation

I read this a few years back and have searched for it multiple times (since I forgot the name) but cannot find it anymore.

The female main character (MC) reincarnates into a baby. When she is a few years old, she gets a teacher to learn how to summon sprits, but she is impatient and the night before, she tries to do it herself. She draws the magic circle and then summons the spirit. She summons a spirit that needs to live in/eat metal and it lives in a candleholder.

The next day, she meets with her teacher and they confirm she has an affinity for water spirits, so the teacher helps her summons the lowest water spirit undine. When she ask the teacher about the spirit she summoned the night before, the teacher thinks she's lying because there is no such thing as a metal spirit.

The story then makes a skip and the MC is 18. She is making a summoning circle to summon the highest water spirit. She succeeds and becomes the youngest person to ever do so. The story was not completed back then and that was where it ended. It was just a few chapters but I really wish to read it again.

Thanks in advance to anyone who took the time to read this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Golden-Haired Summoner](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-golden-haired-summoner)*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/the-golden-haired-summoner).

> Following the trauma of a studying-induced death, Jinny is reborn into a fantastical realm filled with magic, orcs, and talking spirits. As Geenie Crowell, the daughter of a noble and a bona fide genius, everyone has big plans for her, including her new parents, teachers, and even the king! Not too keen on all these high expectations that might end badly for her again, Geenie thinks up the perfect way out from slaving over a hot magic wand: if she becomes a summoner, she'll be able to summon a spirit and have them do all the work! But Geenie will soon learn that there’s more to it all than just adorable spirit companions and collecting mana. Being a summoner comes with great responsibility–and dangerous consequences as well.

[image: Cover image]

The MC reincarnates as a baby and is promptly hailed as a genius as she retains her adult intelligence. Not wanting to study herself to death a second time, she latches on to the idea of becoming a spirit summoner in order to have summoned spirits do all her work for her.

She is given a special teacher at her academy, as they don't want to lose her genius. This still involves lots of courses, and she's impatient, so she follows a book she discovered by chance in the library to create an ancient summoning circle and summon a strange spirit. It is explicitly referred to as a "metal" spirit, and ends up residing in a candlestick. It can move between other metal objects, but as I recall she mostly keeps it as a candlestick.

[image: Geenie showing off her candlestick]

The screenshot shows her child form and her teacher. He doesn't believe her when she says she summoned a "metal" spirit. There is a timeskip shortly after this; the cover image shows her adult form.